# Unable to resolve 'FirebaseMessaging' class

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I added dependencies

- compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:9.0.0'
- compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'

And i am trying to use firebase upstream. 
Configured firebase in my project and added .jon configuration file also. Now to use upstream, I am trying write "FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();"

But getting error that "e**rror: cannot find symbol class FirebaseMessaging**".

What to do??

Comment: Could you add your dependency block to the question? Also you should be using 9.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You should add Firebase Messaging to your dependencies. I too was stucked in the same situation.
Just add the below line in gradle.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
```

Enjoy!!